# SSL enabled but site refused to load securely

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have site with SSL installed and configured correctly, but for some reason, site refused to load via https when try to load and prefer http instead. I made a several tests and put this into .htaccess (found some of answers here on stack):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} etrustbux\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://etrustbux.com/$1 [R,L]
```

but when insert previous posted code into .htaccess a get :

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

error into browser. From [here](https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/93aa84b8-eeff-4630-9762-4f3e7ab37bed) all seems fine, and its really weird why refused to load.. Server is Apache. Configuration [here](http://etrustbux.com/info.php)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "site refused to load"?

Comment: Just curious: Do you use Wordpress?

Comment: No. Its php script.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =etrustbux.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.etrustbux.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

This will also accommodate subdomains

Comment: Get 500 Internal Server Error when add this rules to my htaccess. https://i.imgur.com/oM5mNsD.png?1

Maybe this will help> http://etrustbux.com/info.php

Comment: Do you have anything in your php or httpd error logs?